# Can I separate the 2 types of syntax that call copy constructors into 2 different methods?

Tags: c++, g++, copy-constructor, constructor-overloading

Since a copy constructor can be invoked by constructing with another object of the same type as the argument or by assignment, I was wondering if was possible to separate the two.

I tried making 2 variations (where the only difference was the line of code used to copy the object) and generating assembly for both, but the assembly output was exactly the same, which leads me to believe that it's not possible to differentiate them, unless it is just 'optimised out'.

Can I have 2 different copy constructors, one for `Thing thing2(thing1)` and one for `Thing thing2 = thing1`?

```
#include <iostream>
class Thing {
public:
    Thing() {
    }
    Thing(const Thing& from) {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    Thing thing1;
    Thing thing2(thing1); // This line is identical
    Thing thing3 = thing1; // to this one
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They are not exactly the same. Making the constructor `explicit`, i.e. `explicit Thing(const Thing& from);`, will show the difference.

Comment: Do you intend to try to do anything useful if you manage to make this distinction? I'd be curious if there is any practical application for that.

Comment: Maybe a bit hyper-technical, but the `=` in `Thing thing3 = thing1;` is not an assignment. It just looks like it. <g>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in your particular example, you can distinguish between the 2 versions like this:

```
class Thing {
public:
    Thing() {
    }
    explicit Thing(Thing& from) {
        std::cout << "Constructor One\n";
    }
    Thing(Thing const&) {
        std::cout << "Constructor Two\n";
    }
};
```

and now the initializations will call different constructors:

```
int main()
{
    Thing thing1;
    Thing thing2(thing1);  // Constructor One  
    Thing thing3 = thing1; // Constructor Two
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ncbEEq).

Note that this only works for your example because `thing1` is non-const. If it's const, then both initialization versions will call the 2nd constructor.